# How show VSTO Word Add-In on the base of Author name?

Tags: c#, vsto

I have created a Add-In which provide a Customize menu.

I want to set condition to show or active this menu. 
I just want to show this menu if Author name of the Ms Word is "MyMenuTool".

Please suggest how to achieve above requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare DocumentOpen event handler in your ThisAddIn_Startup method.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DocumentOpen += DocumentOpened;
}
```

Then in your Document Open event handler check for the required author name like this

```
private void DocumentOpened(object sender)
{
    Word._Document document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
    Office.DocumentProperties properties = document.BuiltInDocumentProperties;
    if((properties["Author"].Value as string).Equals("MyMenuTool"))
    {
        //Show or activate the menu
    }
}
```